# Centos IPTables - Allow Traffic for Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: iptables

I know that:

211.95.79.186/24, it would allow 211.95.79.0 all the way up to 211.95.79.255.

and

211.95.0.0/16, it would allow 211.95.0.0 all the way up to 211.95.255.255.

and

192.168.1.30-50, it would allow 192.168.1.30 all the way up to 192.168.1.50 ?? <-- is that correct ?

but how do I **allow** the following:

31.223.**128.0** all the way up to 31.223.**159.255** ?

Comment: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Comment: Thanks for the link it's great. but how do I do the following ? Allow from: 31.223.128.0 all the way up to 31.223.159.255 ??

Comment: @compcobalt have you looked at the rules in my answer? `--src-range X-Y` should work for any arbitrary range of addresses.

Comment: @plasmid87 that would be super cool and easy to do if I had access to a config file for the firewall :(

Comment: @compcobalt If you don't have "access to a config file for the firewall" how do you expect to make ***ANY*** changes? Come now my good man, be reasonable! We're sysadmins, not magicians!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `iprange` module. e.g.,:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 24.250.0.0-24.250.127.255 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 119.165.128.0-119.165.255.255 -j ACCEPT
```

EDIT:

As this must be done through the Webmin interface, try `31.223.128.0/19`. Confirm [here](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php) with "Mask Bits" set to 19.

Comment: I'm using Webmin to insert the ip addresses, I cannot add this anywhere ?

Comment: @compcobalt if webmin doesn't provide direct iptables editing, I suggest following [their instructions](http://www.webmin.com/firewall.html) for configuring the firewall and use the commands listed in my answer.

Comment: @compcobalt I've updated my answer to reflect the constraint of doing this via Webmin.